# How to change the rails asset location of the javascripts template folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

Currently to require a javascript template file, I put the file in `app/assets/javascripts/templates`, and include a line like this in a javascript file:

```
// = require templates/cool_thing.jst
```

And then I access the template in my javascript like this:

```
JST['templates/cool_thing']
```

This works fine, of course, but it requires having my templates put in a subdirectory of the `assets/javascript` folder. Templates are a large part of my project and I'd really like them to have their own space.

Ideally, I'd love to have my rails 3 assets folder organized like this:

```
- Assets
  - javascripts
  - templates
  - stylesheets
```

And then require the templates like thus:

```
// = require templates/cool_thing.jst
```

And access them in javascript like this:

```
JST['cool_thing']
```

Is this possible, and if so how is it done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your application.rb config:

```
config.assets.paths << File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'assets', 'templates')
```

Comment: Thank you! That is most of what I'm looking for. The only issue now is that to require a template means doing this: `// = require template_name`. This means templates can't share the name of javascript files. Do you know if its possible to use the assets/templates like you showed me, while at the same time requiring the template files with `// = require template/template_name`?

Comment: You would have to put them in a directory inside templates called 'templates'. :-) While annoying, your original method does allow the path. The only other option is to prepend the template filenames with something.

Comment: Yeah, it'll be a touch annoying, but will work. Thanks Richard!

Comment: I figured out a good trick -- just wrap JST in a convenience function that prepends "templates/". Easy peasy! I submitted an edit to add it to your answer.

Comment: Rails.root is a Pathname, so you can Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'templates') instead